# Gradient of a function with respect to a non-square matrix

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider the following function of a matrix $W$ of size $d \times p$.

$$f(W)= aW (W^T \Sigma W)^{-1} W^Ta^T$$

Here: $a \in R^{d}$ is  a constant vector, $\Sigma$ is a constant covariance matrix. I am trying to compute the gradient of $f(W)$ w.r.t $W$.

I have checked the matrix cookbook at

/http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf

However, none of the formula provided on the document helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is tedious but not difficult. Using the expansion $(A+H)^{-1} = A^{-1}- A^{-1} H A^{-1} + \cdots$ compute $f(W+\Delta)-f(W)$ and discard all but the first order terms in $\Delta$.

Comment: Thanks, I got what I need using Wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+tranpose(a)*W+*inv(+tranpose(W)*C*W+)+*tranpose(W)+*a+with+respect+to+W